# Get values from variables array based on another variable values

Tags: arrays, r

Assume I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(AccountNumber = 1:5, ActivationDate = c(201001L, 
201002L, 201001L, 201010L, 201008L), Payments_201001 = c(100L, 
NA, 2342L, NA, NA), Payments_201002 = c(200L, 100L, 235L, NA, 
NA), Payments_201003 = c(100L, 100L, 111L, NA, NA), Payments_201004 = c(100L, 
100L, 144L, NA, NA), Payments_201005 = c(150L, 100L, NA, NA, 
NA), Payments_201006 = c(150L, 100L, NA, NA, NA), Payments_201007 = c(NA, 
100L, NA, NA, NA), Payments_201008 = c(NA, 100L, NA, NA, 144L
), Payments_201009 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 159L), Payments_201010 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 100L, 100L)), .Names = c("AccountNumber", "ActivationDate", 
"Payments_201001", "Payments_201002", "Payments_201003", "Payments_201004", 
"Payments_201005", "Payments_201006", "Payments_201007", "Payments_201008", 
"Payments_201009", "Payments_201010"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Basically I have one variable showing when an account has been activated and an array of payment variables corresponding to the month of data.

What I am trying to do is to create a new array `Payments1-Payments10` that correspond to the payments accounts has made in months 1 to 10 starting from activation. Specifically - `Payments1` should correspond to the amount coming from the first month AFTER Activation(datarow 1 -> value should come from Payments_201002->200), `Payments2` to the amount from  2 months after activation etc...

What I tried doing is used the following script to move elements on the left:

```
single.shift<- function (x){
      r <- rle(is.na(x))
      if(!r$values[1]) return(x)
      num <- r$length[1]
      c(x[-1:-num], rep(NA, num))
}
 t(apply(x, 1, single.shift))
```

In my specific scenario is not applicable due to data specifics (month of activation also having payments, gaps in history, etc.)

If it was SAS I would have done the following:
Create 2 Arrays:

```
Array Pay1 Payments201001-Payments201010;
Array Pay2 Payments1-Payments10;
```

I would take the index of Activation DAte and create new var -> e.g. if ActivationDate = 201001 then IndexVar = 1, ActivationDate=201003 then IndexVar = 3, etc.

Since SAS works on rows I can then use loops

```
do i = 1 to 10-IndexVar; /*(since for the 10th month there's no one month AFTER)*/
Pay2[i] = Pay1[IndexVar+i];
end;
```

I am not being able to do it for now in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd solve it. I do not use `ActivationDate` at all, since I suppose that it is defined by the first non-NA entry. I also remove trailing NAs with a handy `na.trim` function from the `zoo` package.

```
payment_cumul <- apply(df[, -(1:2)], 1, function(x) 
{
  y <- na.trim(x, sides = "left")
  y[is.na(y)] <- 0
  cumsum(y)  
})

get_i_months <- function(i) 
{
  sapply(payment_cumul, function(x) {
    z <- x[i]
    if (is.na(z)) return(x[length(x)])
    z
  })
}
# payments for the first month since activation
get_i_months(1)
#Payments_201001 Payments_201002 Payments_201001 Payments_201010 Payments_201008 
#            100             100            2342             100             144 

# payments for 10 first months
get_i_months(10)
#Payments_201010 Payments_201010 Payments_201010 Payments_201010 Payments_201010 
#            800             700            2832             100             403
```

Comment: Hi tonytonov - thanks for the answer! The issue is twofold-I actually do not need cumulatives but rather to know nominal amount of payment 1 month after activation, 2 months after activation, etc... But this is not the major show-stopper for me. The real issue is that for some month I have NA payments IN the month of activation - so removing leading blanks does not work for me - I should be able to refer to 1 month after activation knowing what actually the activation date is....

Comment: Then I'm afraid the code will be significantly more complicated, since you'll have to parse the date. Okay, I might revisit this in some time.